# External IP address not listed for IIS website bindings Google Cloud

Tags: iis, google-cloud-platform, ip, google-compute-engine, windows-server-2019

I used to had a dedicated server but now I am migrating everything to a google Cloud Platform. In Computer Engine I have created a VM windows server. I am trying to add my first website, but when I try to bind my external IP address, this is not listed for IIS website bindings. In this case, I don't know how can I link the external IP to my website. I want to add multiple websites to that server. The only option that I have is bind to an internal IP address.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/self-hosting-series-why-cannot-my-web-server-iis-be-reached-from-anywhere-else-8da0e0b252ef External IP address is used by the Google Cloud itself as gateway, so you can only bind to the internal IP address assigned to this IIS machine.

Comment: You do not want to bind to an IP address (there are exceptions). You should bind to `0.0.0.0` which means all interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. Now I know that you can add several network interfaces (one per core) but only in the first step of the VM creation and you can bind External to an internal IP. In the machine, there is not possible to see external IP.